# AmazonSES: DKIM pdd.yandex.ru

Tags: php, email, amazon, яндекс-почта, dkim

Как настроить DKIM на пдд.яндекс?

Что я только не пробовал. Но письмо на gmail всё время идет в спам!
Только с HTML идет в спам кстати.

Comment: Никак похоже. У них такого вроде нет. Забить что ли на этот gmail.

Comment: «Что, опять?!» Только на одном GMail аккаунте идёт в спам, или на нескольких? HTML ссылается на внешние картинки/CSS/файлы? - на каком домене? GMail подвтерждает, что DKIM подпись верна - в спамовых письмах (см. заголовки)?